# How to position and resize React Bootstrap Tooltip before displaying it on the DOM?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, react-bootstrap

I have a react bootstrap tooltip that works well unless I'm close to the edges of the window. In that case I want the tooltip not to be cut off but resized to accomadate the full text and have borders on all sides.

I also want the tooltip arrow to point just above the trigger element (in my case the 'i' icon).

My guess is that this requires working with the DOM once the `ReactBootstrap.Tooltip` has been rendered. I need to be able to calculate it's current size and window top and left offset positions and then re-position/re-size it.

Here's my current code (in CoffeeScript):

```
define [
  'jquery',
  'es6-shim',
  'react',
  'react-bootstrap'
], ($, _shim, React, ReactBootstrap) ->

  {div, i, h2} = React.DOM

  ToolTipHint = React.createFactory(
    React.createClass

      render: ->
        tooltip = ReactBootstrap.Tooltip className: 'hint-content',
          h2 className: 'hint-title', @props.fieldName
          div className: 'hint-text', @props.tooltip

        ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger(
          trigger: ['hover']
          placement: 'top'
          overlay: tooltip
          delayShow: 300
          deplayHide: 150,
            div className: 'hint-icon-container',
              i className: 'gg-icon-tooltip hint-icon'
        )
  )
```

And here's the screenshot of the problem:

[image: React Boostrap Tooltip example]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I had this very same problem when my trigger was close to the right side of the window. I fixed it by overwriting the max-width of the .popover class to:

```
.popover{
  max-width: none;
}
```

and defining a width to the element inside the popover.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip has a "container" (just like the original bootstrap component that you can set). By default it is the body. 
Try to play a bit with this option. I can't tell from what you provided what value you should use.